# vim function system invalid argument

Tags: vim, system, sas

I'm trying to use the following vim function to run my sas on windows, but I always got error message saying the argument for system is invalid.

Could some vim expert help me out?

myy sas is installed in:

C:\Program Files\SAS\SAS\9.1\sas.exe

```
function! RunSASonCurrentFile()
    " Make sure this is a SAS program file (ends with .sas) so that
    " we don't run SAS on a log file or similar.
    :let checkSASpgm=match(expand("%"),"\.sas")

    " If we did not match .sas in the file name, end this function with
    " a warning msg
    if checkSASpgm==-1
       :echo "*** Current file is not a SAS program.  SAS run has been canceled."
       :return
    endif

    " Ask user if we want to run SAS so we don't accidentally run it.
    :let l:answer = input("Run SAS? Y/N ") 
    :if (l:answer == "Y" || l:answer == "y")

    " If file has been modified, save it before running
    if exists(&modified)
       :echo "*** Saving modified file before SAS run..."
       :w
    endif

    " Run SAS on path/file name (modify to your location of sas)
    :echo "*** Running SAS..."
    "let returntxt = system("/usr/local/bin/sas -nodms " . shellescape(expand("%:p")))
    " The following may work for your Windows system. Comment the line above and uncomment 
    " the two lines below and make them one long line.
    let returntxt = system("\"" . shellescape("C:\\Program\ Files\\SAS\\SAS\9.1\\sas.exe") 
    ".  "\ -nosplash" . "\ -sysin" . "\ " . shellescape(expand("%:p")) .  "\"") 

    " Shows the return messages from the SAS commandline (may be useful
    " if no log produced)
    :echo "*** SAS commandline: " . returntxt

    :call LoadSASLogList()

    :else
    :echo "SAS Run cancelled."

    " endif for the Run SAS? check
    :endif
  endfunction
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim patch 7.3.443 changed the behavior of the shell escaping (which continues to be a trouble spot, due to the arcane Windows shell escaping rules). Whereas beforehand, one had to enclose the entire command line in double quotes if it contained a (itself quoted) executable with spaces in it, these now have to be removed. Try the following:

```
let returntxt = system(shellescape('C:\Program Files\SAS\SAS\9.1\sas.exe') . ' -nosplash -sysin ' . shellescape(expand('%:p')))
```

This also avoids some additional escaping by using single quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the exact text of your function, I think you're missing a second \ between SAS and 9.1 in the line `let returntxt = system("\"" . shellescape("C:\\Program\ Files\\SAS\\SAS\9.1\\sas.exe")`.

Comment: i tried to correct it.  does not work. thank you for answering me.

Comment: It says invalid argagument for System(....).  I'am afraid that I passed a wrong string.